# How to download a file to the system directory?

Tags: java, android

How to use the Download Manager to download a file to the `system/app` folder and not to the `Downloads` folder?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, that is not an option. The app that processes `DownloadManager` requests will not have write access to that directory.

Comment: Then tell me what is needed for this?

Comment: @soundsofnature: Sorry, but I do not know what "this" is.

Answer (score 1):

The /system/app directory is protected and you won't have access to it from a non-rooted device. Other than the system it self, no other entity should have write permission to that directory.
The only way for you to achieve that is to root your device

Answer (score -2):

1-In the Chrome Settings menu, select Advanced > Downloads > Location > Change and select a new location.
2-To specify a location each time, go to Settings > Advanced > Downloads > Ask where to save each file before downloading.
3-To find a download, go to Menu > Downloads.

Comment: And where does the browser to this issue?